# UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: laravel-5

Getting error after installing dompdf

[2020-01-28 18:23:03] local.ERROR: UnexpectedValueException: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php:399

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I was trying to return a result object without even converting it into JSON format from the server-side. Use a loop to traverse through your result set and store it into an array then try using **json_encode($your_data)** function for returning to the client-side. I request you to share your code for a better understanding of your problem statement.